# Could auto-change the public static String parameter?

Tags: android, static-members

The class contain this parameter like thie

```
public class Global {
    public static String USER_ID = "";
    public static String USER_NAME = "";
    public static String USER_PASSWORD = "";
}
```

the `USER_ID`,I set once when do login.(for example Global.USER_ID = "12345").
And a thread running on the background do that every 5 minute post some data(contains this `USER_ID`) to webservice.

the question is 
when the thread running long long time (about one day). 
I found the parameter `USER_ID` return back to "", is not the "12345".

Why???

anyone know it?

Comment: used shared preference for save password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your class is removed from the memory by class loader (during GC) and it is loaded next time you use Global class.

My Suggestion will be to use Singelton class for this you can have something like this

```
public class Global {
    public String USER_ID = "";
    public String USER_NAME = "";
    public String USER_PASSWORD = "";

    //constructor 
   private Global(){
    // just to prevent object creation from outside
   }
    //static reference
    public static Global global=null;
    public Global getInstance(){    
     return ((global!=null)? global : (global=new Global()) ;
    }
}
```

Now wherever you want to use this class you can get this object, the singelton logic ensures that their is only one object which is shared among all.

You can get the reference in your threads using

```
global = Global.getInstance();
```

Now you can use variables i.e. **USER_ID** using **global.USER_ID**

Since you have a reference of global object GC will not remove that from memory till your thread is alive.

**NOTE**
I have used public variables just for the illustration however they are not recommended in most cases.

**EDIT**

For saving user data I recommend **SharedPreferences** and you can use them as follows:-

```
private final String YourAppName_PREFS_NAME = "chooseAMeaningFulName";
private final String YourAppName_USERNAME = "username";
private final String YourAppName_PASSWORD = "password";

 /*This function will save the user name and password for providing Automatically login in future*/

       public void saveUserData() {
          if ( rememberMeChckbox.isChecked() ) {
            //      Log.i("loginFrag", "Saving userName: Pass " + userName + " : " + password);
            loginActivity.getSharedPreferences(YourAppName_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(YourAppName_USERNAME, userName)
                  .putString(YourAppName_PASSWORD, password).commit();
          } else {
            loginActivity.getSharedPreferences(YourAppName_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().remove(RBR_USERNAME).remove(RBR_PASSWORD).commit();
          }
        }

        /*This function returns the previous data from the SharedPreferences and fills the UserName and Password Text Box*/
        private void getPreviousUserData() {
          SharedPreferences preferences = loginActivity.getSharedPreferences(YourAppName_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
          userName = preferences.getString(YourAppName_USERNAME, null);
          password = preferences.getString(YourAppName_PASSWORD, null);
          //      Log.i("loginFrag", "Got userName: Pass " + userName + " : " + password);
          if ( userName != null ) {
            uText.setText(userName);
          } else {
            uText.setText("android");
          }
          if ( password != null ) {
            passText.setText(password);
          } else {
            passText.setText("android");
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Credentials {
    private Context context;
    private  final String USERID = "USER_ID";
    private final String USER_NAME = "USER_NAME";
    private  final String PASSWORD = "Password";
    private  final String KEY="SaveCredentials";


     public Credentials(Context mcontext) {
        super();
        this.context = mcontext;
    }


    public boolean saveCredentials(String userId,String password,String UserName) {
            Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString(USERID,userId);
            editor.putString(USER_NAME,UserName);
                editor.putString(PASSWORD,password);
            return editor.commit();
        }
    public ArrayList<String> restoreCredentials() {
        ArrayList<String> credentials=new ArrayList<String>();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

       String userid= sharedPreferences.getString(USERID, null);
    String userName=sharedPreferences.getString(USER_NAME,null);
     String password=sharedPreferences.getString(PASSWORD,null);
       credentials.add(userid);
      credentials.add(userName);
       credentials.add(password);
        return credentials;
    }
   public void deleteCredentials()
   {
       Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
   }

}
```

Comment: user this class for save password,restore,delete credentials.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UserDetail {
    public String USER_ID = "";
    public String USER_NAME = "";
    public String USER_PASSWORD = "";

    public static void setUSER_ID(String USER_ID)
    {
        this.USER_ID = USER_ID;
    }

    public static String getUSER_ID()
    {
        return USER_ID;
    }   
}
```

In your `Globals Class` declare

```
public static UserDetail userDetails = new UserDetail();
```

In your code first set the values like

```
Globals.userDetals.setUSER_ID("12345");
```

and get the value from the same Like

```
String USER_ID = Globals.userDetails.getUSER_ID();
```